# how to make fields read-only in Sharepoint list without infopath

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-list

I'm new to sharepoint.I am creating sharepoint list with some columns. that columns should be read only which i want.

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint classic view, you could use CSR for this requirement.

Check the  demo [CSR code samples #8 (Read-only SP Controls)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Sample-8-List-add-and-edit-d228b751).